# SQL Server stored procedure takes 1' 18" to run... seems long

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, optimization

Sure could use some optimization help here. I've got a stored procedure which takes approximately 1 minute, 18 seconds to run and it gets even worse when I run the asp.net page which hits it.

Some stats:

- `tbl_Allocation` typically has approximately 55K records
- `CS_Ready` has ~300
- `Redate_Orders` has ~2000

Here is the code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Order_Display]                        
/*                  
(                   
   @parameter1 int = 5,                 
   @parameter2 datatype OUTPUT                  
)                   
*/                  
AS                      
   /* SET NOCOUNT ON */                 
BEGIN
   WTIH CS_Ready AS
   (                        
      SELECT        
         tbl_Order_Notes.txt_Order_Only As CS_Ready_Order
      FROM            
         tbl_Order_Notes 
      INNER JOIN                        
         tbl_Order_Notes_by_line ON tbl_Order_Notes.txt_Order_Only = SUBSTRING(tbl_Order_Notes_by_line.txt_Order_Key_by_line, 1, CHARINDEX('-', tbl_Order_Notes_by_line.txt_Order_Key_by_line, 0) - 1)
      WHERE        
         (tbl_Order_Notes.bin_Customer_Service_Review = 'True') 
         AND (tbl_Order_Notes_by_line.dat_Recommended_Date_by_line IS NOT NULL) 
         AND (tbl_Order_Notes_by_line.bin_Redate_Request_by_line = 'True')
         OR (tbl_Order_Notes.bin_Customer_Service_Review = 'True') 
         AND (tbl_Order_Notes_by_line.dat_Recommended_Date_by_line IS NULL) 
         AND (tbl_Order_Notes_by_line.bin_Redate_Request_by_line = 'False' 
              OR tbl_Order_Notes_by_line.bin_Redate_Request_by_line IS NULL)
   ),                       
   Redate_Orders AS
   (                        
      SELECT DISTINCT 
         SUBSTRING(txt_Order_Key_by_line, 1, CHARINDEX('-', txt_Order_Key_by_line, 0) - 1) AS Redate_Order_Number
      FROM
         tbl_Order_Notes_by_line                        
      WHERE        
         (bin_Redate_Request_by_line = 'True')
   )                        
   SELECT DISTINCT 
      tbl_Allocation.*, tbl_Order_Notes.*, 
      tbl_Order_Notes_by_line.*,
      tbl_Max_Promised_Date_1.Max_Promised_Ship, 
      tbl_Max_Promised_Date_1.Max_Scheduled_Pick, 
      Redate_Orders.Redate_Order_Number, CS_Ready.CS_Ready_Order,
      tbl_Most_Recent_Comments.Abbr_Comment, 
      MRC_Line.Abbr_Comment as Abbr_Comment_Line
   FROM            
      tbl_Allocation 
   INNER JOIN                       
      tbl_Max_Promised_Date AS tbl_Max_Promised_Date_1 ON tbl_Allocation.num_Order_Num = tbl_Max_Promised_Date_1.num_Order_Num 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      CS_Ready ON tbl_Allocation.num_Order_Num = CS_Ready.CS_Ready_Order 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      Redate_Orders ON tbl_Allocation.num_Order_Num = Redate_Orders.Redate_Order_Number
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      tbl_Order_Notes ON Hidden_Order_Only = tbl_Order_Notes.txt_Order_Only 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      tbl_Order_Notes_by_line ON Hidden_Order_Key = tbl_Order_Notes_by_line.txt_Order_Key_by_line
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      tbl_Most_Recent_Comments ON Cast(tbl_Allocation.Hidden_Order_Only as varchar) = tbl_Most_Recent_Comments.Com_ID_Parent_Key
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      tbl_Most_Recent_Comments as MRC_Line ON Cast(tbl_Allocation.Hidden_Order_Key as varchar) = MRC_Line.Com_ID_Parent_Key
   ORDER BY 
      num_Order_Num, num_Line_Num                       
End                 
RETURN
```

What suggestions do you have to make this execute within five seconds or less?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Do you have appropriate indexes on your data?

Comment: Since every little bit helps, do not select *.  Select just the fields you need.  While that might not affect the execution time, it will reduce the data transfer time.

Comment: Regarding execution time, the lack of a where clause means you are querying the whole darn database.  Also, filtering on function results, such as cast(), slows down production.

Comment: Have you looked at the **execution plan** for the query?

Comment: You need to post the query plan (Actual, not Estimated) where we can examine it.

Comment: Using `SELECT DISTINCT` with `*` is a pretty good indication that you are doing something wrong.  This is generally a red flag for a past shot-in-the-dark attempt to fix a logical problem with the query.  It's rarely correct and almost always performs poorly.

Comment: It seems pretty likely that you are getting cross-multiplication with all of those outer joins and are trying band-aid it with the `DISTINCT *`.  Performance aside, this is very unlikely to be a logically correct query, but you *need* to make sure its logically correct before you start worrying about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have appropriate indices defined, you still have several things that suggest problems.

1) You have 2 select distinct clauses in this query -- in a good design, distinct clauses are are rarely needed

2) The first inner join uses

tbl_Order_Notes_by_line 
ON tbl_Order_Notes.txt_Order_Only 
    = SUBSTRING(tbl_Order_Notes_by_line.txt_Order_Key_by_line, 1, 
          CHARINDEX('-', tbl_Order_Notes_by_line.txt_Order_Key_by_line, 0) - 1)

This looks like a horrible join criteria -- function calls during the join that prevent any decent query optimization. My guess is that your are using data the has internal meaning and that you are parsing the internal meaning during the join, e.g.,

PartNumber = AAA-BBBB_NNNNNNNN
where AAA is the Country product line and BBBB is the year & month of the design

If you must have coded fields like these AND you need to manipulate them, put the codes into separate database fields and created a computer column -- or even a plan copy of the full part number field if the combined field is unusually complex.

This point is not a performance issue, but you have a long sub-query using multiple AND & OR clauses. I know the rules for operator precedence, you may know the rules for operator precedence, but will the next guy? Will you remember them an 1:00 when stuff is broken.

ADDED

You are using 2 common table expressions. I know others say it does not happen, but I don't really trust the query optimizer for CTE's -- I have had to recode CTE based joins for performance issues on several occasions -- creating an actual view equivalent to the CTE and using that instead can be a significant speedup. May well depend on the version of SQL server, but if you are running an older version I would definitely wonder about CTR optimization. -- This is not as important as the first 2 things I've mentioned, try to fix those first.

ADDED

I'm going to harsh on CTEs again, as I did not really explain why they are bad for performance, and it was bothering me. If you don't have performance issues, and you like the syntax, they can be useful in at least limited usage, personally I don't normally recommend them for anything more than that -- and given that it is MS specific syntactical sugar, I really can't recommend them much at all.

I think the primary reason that CTEs don't get optimized well is that there are no statistics for the opimizer to use. If you are pulling a lot of rows into a CTE, you are probably better off creating #temptable and populating it. You can even add an index or two to your #temptable and the optimizer can figure out how to use them too. A @temp table is similar, but at least through sql 2012, the were no faster than @temp that I could tell -- supposedly new goodness in server 2014 help this.

A CTE is really just a temporary view in disguise, which I why I suggested you can replace with a real view to better better performance (and you often can), or you can populate a temp table and sometime get even better performance.

Comment: ADDED CTE comment to answer

Comment: Correctly written non-recursive CTEs are never the cause of performance problems.  They can't be, they're just subquery aliases.  Your speculation about this and how they are optimized is entirely off-base.

Comment: Yes, they are a subquery alias which is logically equivalent to a temporary view. And they both share all of the potential performance problems that I explained briefly as compared to the alternatives. I prefer to explain as a temp-view as that seems simpler for most sql developers to understand.

Comment: Neither Views *nor* CTEs can have the problems that you claim because they have nothing to do with SQL Server's statistical optimization.  They are not rowsources but rowsource *expressions* that get translated into the physical rowsources (i.e., table data) and corresponding query logic.  Only these physical rowsources can have statistics.  CTEs (and Views and inline Table-Valued Functions) are all just table expression aliases.  They can not cause problems on their own, they just provide an abstract way to express the logic and rowsources of the query.